# Clear all UITextField changes in a UITableView with a UIButton

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a UITableView with a dozen rows, each containing a UITextField.
By default the UITextField contains a placeholder value "Add Value" if the user hasn't previously edited the text field:

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(158, 6, 148, 24)];

NSString *strReplacement = [valueArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if (([strReplacement length] != 0) {
    textField.text = strReplacement;
} else {
    textField.placeholder = @"Add Value";
}

textField.delegate = self;
[cell addSubview:textField];
[textField release];
```

So far so good.

I've also added a UIButton to the footer of the UITableView. 
What I want is to clear all the edited values and refresh all the UITextFields in the UITableView when the user clicks the UIButton.

I can easily enough remove all objects from the valueArray but I can't figure out how to refresh all the UITableView cells to reflect the changes.

Any help is appreciated.
lq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours of trial and error, I came up with this solution. The UIButton "Clear All" invokes the following method:

```
- (IBAction)clearValues:(id)sender {

    // count the number of values in the array (this is the same as the number of rows in the table)
    int count = [valueArray count];

    // remove all values from the array (deletes any user added values):
    [self.valueArray removeAllObjects];

    UITableViewCell *cell;
    UITextField *textField;

    // loop through each row in the table and put nil in each UITextField:
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; ++i) {

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
        cell = [self.wordsTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        // NOTE: Make sure none of your tags are set to 0 since all non-tagged objects are zero.
        // In table construction, your textFieldTags should be: textField.tag=indexPath.row+1;

        textField = (UITextField*)[cell viewWithTag:i+1];
        textField.text = nil;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you're looking for is

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: When I press the UIButton I purge the values in valueArray (and I verify the values are purged) but the replacement values are still populating the UITextFields after reloadData.

Comment: that's odd. you might want to put a breakpoint in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method and see what's the content of `valueArray` in there after the `reloadData`.

Comment: - (IBAction)clearReplacements:(id)sender {             
        [self.valueArray removeAllObjects];
 [myTableView reloadData]; 
} Doesn't reload the table. Using breakpoints code just stops after reloadData.

Comment: ok, when it's stopped inside the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, can you check the contents of `valueArray`? You're using `self.valueArray` in the clear method, but just `valueArray` (the ivar directly) when populating the table view, are you sure those are one and the same? (maybe you declared the property as `copy` or something like that?)

Comment: GDB Stopped after Step when the method clearReplacements ends. It doesn't reload the table, nothing actually happens.

Comment: it doesn't go into `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, then? where did you put the breakpoint? are you sure you're running in Debug and not Release?

Answer (score 1):

Your solution feels weird. Filipe's right that the correct way to do it is with `[wordsTableView reloadData]`, which will cause `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to be called for each visible cell. That method is also called as you scroll through the table, so if reloadData isn't working, you're probably also going to end up with bugs with data not updating correctly as you change it and scroll. In your clearValues method, you're doing the same thing by calling `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

I think the real problem is in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` implementation. That method generally has 2 sections. First, you create or recycle a cell to get a reference with something like:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
```

Inside that if statement is generally the only place you should be adding subviews to your cell. If `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` returns a cell, it should already have the subview.

Then, after that if statement, you populate or update the contents of the subviews. The problem with your original code is that it's populating the text field and adding it as a subview, assuming there isn't already a text field in the cell. So your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` should look something more like this:

```
int textFieldTag = 100;

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(158, 6, 148, 24)];
    [textField setTag:textFieldTag];
    [textField setDelegate:self];
    [cell addSubview:textField];
    [textField release];
}

UITextField *textField = [cell viewWithTag:textFieldTag];
NSString *strReplacement = [valueArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if (([strReplacement length] != 0) {
    textField.text = strReplacement;
} else {
    textField.placeholder = @"Add Value";
}
```

It looks like you may be setting the textField's tag value to the row number, presumably so you can use it in the UITextFieldDelegate. That could also lead to bugs, as if the cell from row 1 is recycled by `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` and becomes row 12, it's going to have an unexpected tag value. Even if it doesn't happen now, it's a bug waiting to happen, and will be tricky to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

Filipe's solution should also work, however, calling `reloadData` should be avoided wherever possible as calling this method has a high performance overhead.

You need some class that has a reference to both the *UIButton* instance as well as all the instances of the *UITextField* that you have on the screen/in the table. Sounds like the perfect job for your *UITableView* controller subclass!

In your code above, why don't you also add each *UITextField* that you create to an *NSArray* of text fields that lives in your *UITableView* controller? Then when the user presses the *UIButton*, the action can call some method in your controller class, which loops through all the *UITextField* elements in the *NSArray* setting the `text` property of each instance to `@""`.

Warning: If you're reusing cells then you may have to ensure that the controller's *NSArray* of *UITextFields* is being updated properly.

Comment: I'm using a tag property for each of the UITextField elements, but I'm not clear on how to address them in a separate method?